Looking for an 80's or early 90's Horror Film About Kids In a Halfway House
I vaguely remember this movie from around 4-6 years old, so my memory of these glimpses have grown rather fuzzy. I am desperate to find it, or at least its title. 
From what I can recall, it centers on a group of teens at a sort of halfway house (similar to the setting in Friday the 13th part 5: A New Beginning).
I seem to remember a new kid coming and he appeared to have these powers or some supernatural link. I remember a scene where the teens make fun of him and one of the characters gets injured.
I also remember a bizarre scene where a character has some psychotic break because some girl rejects.
There is a character that is overweight and super obnoxious (Kind of reminds me of Mark Holton who played Ozzie in Leprechaun (93), Chubby in Teen Wolf and Francis in Pee-Wees Big Adventure). But based on researching his filmography, I can't find anything even remotely close. 
That is literally all I have to go off. Any help would be appreciated.

It might be the American horror film directed by Eric Weston Evilspeak (1981)

Plot:(Wikipedia)

Years ago during the Dark Ages, Satanic leader Father Estaban (Richard
  Moll) and his followers are approached by a church official on the
  shore of Spain, telling them that they are banished from Spain and
  denied God's grace unless they renounce Satan and their evil ways.
In the present, Stanley Coopersmith (Clint Howard) is young cadet at
  an American military academy. He remains as a social outcast who is
  bullied by his classmates due to him being an orphan, and treated
  unfairly by his instructors who believe him to be inept at everything.
  When he is punished for no clear reason by cleaning the church cellar,
  he finds a room belonging to Father Estaban which contains books of
  black magic along with Father Estaban's diary. He then uses his
  computer skills to translate the book from Latin into English, in
  which the translation describes Estaban as a Satanist and the book
  contains rituals for performing the Black Mass along with a promise by
  Estaban citing "I Will Return".
Waking up the late the next morning, Coopersmith finds his alarm clock
  unplugged and his clothing tied in knots courtesy of his belligerent
  classmates. This causes him to be tardy for morning classes, and his
  teacher writes him a punishment note to be taken to the school's
  Colonel headmaster in his office. When he's sent to the office,
  Coopersmith accidentally leaves the diary on the desk of the school
  secretary who hides it. While Coopersmith is being made to clean the
  stables as punishment for no reason, the office secretary begins to
  finger the jewels on the front of the diary. Trying to pry the jewels
  out of their settings causes the pigs in the stable to attack
  Coopersmith.
Coopersmith returns to his dormitory room to find his belongings
  scattered by his classmates again, and cannot find his book of black
  magic, assuming that his classmates stole it. He confronts them about
  the supposed theft at a local roller rink, but they deny knowledge of
  the book and he leaves. He then goes to the school's computer lab to
  perform more general research on Satanism even though his book is
  still missing. His allotted time in the lab runs out, and he is forced
  to leave with his research incomplete.
Next Coopersmith appears in the church cellar with computer equipment
  which is assumed to be stolen from the school's computer lab as the
  act itself is never shown. He sets up the computer and runs some
  inquiries into the requirements for a black mass. Searching through
  various bottles in the cellar left by Father Estaban, he attempts to
  initiate a mass but the computer informs him that he is still missing
  crucial ingredients, namely blood and a consecrated host. At this
  point, he is nearly discovered by Reverend Jameson, the church's
  current pastor, who sends him off to the mess hall to eat dinner.
  After arriving at the mess hall too late for lunch, he befriends the
  school's good-natured cook who makes a meal for him and shows him a
  litter of puppies that his dog just had. Coopersmith takes the
  smallest pup for himself, names him Fred and hides him in the church
  cellar.
Coopersmith steals the host from the church, and then notices
  Estaban's portrait on the wall. Using the translation he attempts the
  ritual and is suddenly attacked by his classmates wearing masks and
  robes. After knocking him unconscious they leave. Coopersmith,
  thinking he has successfully performed the ritual is told by his
  computer that the ritual was incomplete and a pentagram appears on the
  computer screen. Coopersmith accidentally wakes the drunken caretaker
  (R.G. Armstrong), who accuses him of being a thief for stealing a
  crowbar. The caretaker attacks Coopersmith, who screams for help, and
  the computer flares to life with a red pentagram on it. An unseen
  force then takes the caretaker's head and turns it completely around
  breaking his neck. Coopersmith then discovers a catacomb filled with
  decapitated skeletal remains and the crypt of Father Estaban. After
  hiding the caretaker's body, he leaves.
Next, the school's secretary is shown at home where she attempts one
  last time to pry the pentagram from the black magic book she stole
  from Coopersmith. She fails, injuring her finger which bleeds. She
  undresses, begins to take a shower and is fatally attacked by
  demonically spawned boars. After watching a beauty pageant at the
  school's pep rally, Coopersmith is attacked by his classmates who tell
  him that if tries to play in the big game tomorrow they'll find and
  kill Fred. After witnessing his beating at the hands of his
  classmates, the hostile and unfriendly school principal kicks
  Coopersmith off the soccer team.
After a night of drinking, Coopersmith's classmates make their way
  into Estaban's hidden room and find Coopersmith's computer program.
  After killing Fred, the computer says that the blood used must be
  human blood. After finding Fred's mutilated body, Coopersmith becomes
  completely enraged. The diary then appears laying on Estaban's casket.
  When a teacher catches Coopersmith in the church stealing the host, he
  follows him to the catacombs where Coopersmith is translating the rest
  of the diary. Coopersmith pledges his life to Satan then kills his
  teacher on a spiked wheel and collects his blood.
Unaware of the ritual being performed below, Coopersmith's classmates,
  the coach, principal, and minister are all in attendance at a service
  above. After successfully performing the ritual, Father Estaban's soul
  then possesses Coopersmith's body and takes up a sword. Meanwhile, a
  nail from the large crucifix hanging over the church's altar is pried
  out by an unseen force and flies across the room and is driven into
  the minister's skull. Coopersmith then rises from the cellar below
  engulfed in flames and wielding a sword. A pack of large black boars
  pours out of the hole in the floor where Coopersmith now hovers above
  everyone else. He then decapitates his principal and his coach. His
  classmates try to flee from the church only to be devoured by the
  boars. In the catacombs, the lead bully tries to escape only to have
  the caretaker come back to life and remove the boy's heart while it is
  still beating. The church burns to the ground.
The caption at the end says that Stanley Coopersmith survived the
  attack, but after witnessing the fiery death of his classmates, he
  went catatonic from shock and was sentenced to Sunnydale Asylum where
  he remains. The end of the film shows Coopersmith's true fate as his
  face appears on the computer screen in the cellar with the words "I
  Will Return".

Movie:Youtube




I don't think Evilspeak is it, but it does seem to have some images that make it a candidate! Gonna hunt it down and check it out. Thanks!
